# How do I perform a modular subtraction of times-of-day in MySQL/MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, time

We can subtract time values in MariaDB/MySQL, as follows:

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF("23:10:11", "22:10:10");
```

Now, if the left-hand-side time is earlier than the right-hand-side, I "simply" get a negative value (actually not so simple, but whatever). What I want to do is to make the differences modular, so that negative values get subtracted from a full day, e.g.:

```
SELECT MAGIC("00:10:11", "23:10:10");
```

... would give me the equivalent of `TIME("01:00:11")`.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Is this any more elegant (it still has lots of 'time values')...

```
SET @end   = "00:10:11";
SET @start = "23:10:10";


SELECT CASE WHEN @end < @start 
            THEN TIMEDIFF(@end,@start) + INTERVAL 1 DAY 
            ELSE TIMEDIFF(@end,@start) END x;
```

It's essentially identical to your solution; just using CASE instead of IF, and removing those redundant TIME() functions.

Comment: Well, slightly, but I was hoping for something like time-modulo operation.

Answer (score 0):

This [works](https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/trymysql.asp?filename=trysql_func_mysql_timediff2), but is ugly:

```
SELECT 
    IF(TIME("00:10:11") < TIME("23:10:10"),
    TIMEDIFF("00:10:11", "23:10:10") + INTERVAL '1' DAY,
    TIMEDIFF("00:10:11", "23:10:10"));
```

Comment: It's not ugly. :-)

Comment: @Strawberry: It's ugly because I have to repeat the time values thrice.